# Change the size of image depending on size of table row

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I have something that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><img src="..." /></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>and more data</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="..." /></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>and more data</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="..." /></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>and more data</td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td><img src="..." /></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>and more data</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="..." /></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>and more data</td></tr>
 </table>
```

The objective is, if possible, to have the image to "kinda" ajust the size of the row.
Let's say, the image is of size 200x200 (in px). I want to image to shrink up to 100px if the row where it is thinner then the size of the image (it it didn't have the image).
For example:

- If, without the image, the row is < 100px height, with image, it becomes 100px height
- If, without the image, the row is 140px height, with image, it stays 140px height
- If, without the image, the row is 200px height, with image, it stays 200px height
- If, without the image, the row is 260px height, with image, it stays 260px height but the image does not get any big than the 100%, which is the 200px.

I have already tried using a min-height + height + max-height for both the td and the img tags but nothing was changing from the browser's perspective.

Notes:

- I'm using the doctype for XHTML 1.1
- I don't need answers that require JavaScript. I already know how to do with JS (even without jQuery). I want a CSS only answer.

Comment: For `max-height`, and `min-height` to work on `td`s, you need to have `table-layout: fixed;` applied on your table. Do you?

Comment: Didn't go exactly as I wanted... I'll try another approach

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td height="100">
            <img src="http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/tartare-saumon-creme-salade-harengs-pommes-de-terre-800.jpg" style="width:auto; height:100%;"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jd9QS/1/)

Comment: That code is not valid XHTML1.1 so, that will never be a code I'd use! I will ***never*** use deprecated stuff when I write my code.

Comment: Ok, brunoais. You don't like to use deprecated stuff, but you use table for images. Where is a logic? May be using of div/ul/li tags will be better? And what's wrong with this code, why it is not valid?

Comment: I use tables for tabular data. This is tabular data. I just gave you what you need to help me. I cannot publish any of the code I'm using for the program I'm working on. It's part of the contract.